# How to debug C# console app with VS Code on Windows 11 ARM64?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, arm64

I'm running the insider preview version of Windows 11 for ARM64 and installed the Visual Studio Code ARM64 build.

Using `dotnet new` (SDK 6 is installed) I was able to create a simple console app. It runs successfully using `dotnet run`.

If, however, I try to debug the project from withing VS Code using ".NET Core Launch", I'm getting this error:

> Error processing 'configurationDone' request. This version of the
> Visual Studio Remote Debugger (MSVSMON.EXE) cannot be used to debug
> ARM64 processes or dumps. Please use the ARM64 version instead.

What do I need to install/configure to make this work?

Comment: After some more trial and error, I uninstalled VSCode and installed the latest insider version (1.63.0-insider) and now it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of this writing, the answer is to use the latest insider version (1.63.0-insider) of Visual Studio Code.

This particularly interesting, as the Apple Silicon version, which is also ARM code, does not require the insider build.